# React firebase clarification issue for read operation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to read through the documents in a particular collection in firebase using react but I'm getting an empty array with an object which i'm not able to access .

```
let finalList = [];

finalResultArray.forEach((document) => {
      db.collection("collection_name")
        .where("id", "==", document.id)
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
          const data = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
          finalList.push(...data);
        });
    });
```

Output:

```
[]
0: {
      address: "xxx", 
      area: "yyy", 
      city: "BENGALURU", 
      contact_person: "abcd", 
   , 
   …}
```

I expect the output of the array to be

```
[
  {
    address: "xxxx", 
    area: "yyy", 
    city: "BENGALURU", 
    contact_person: "abcd", 
  }
]
```

Someone help me through it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with:

```
      finalList.push(data);
```